# responsive footer setting for laptop and mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I have a footer like this and the code is as follows:

```
 <div class = "footer">
    <hr>
    <div class="beian">company <a target="_blank" 
     href="URL">company number</a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
 hr {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 8px auto;
   height: 0;
   width: 50%;
   max-height: 0;
   font-size: 1px;
   line-height: 0;
   clear: both;
   border: none;
   border-top: 1px solid #808080;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
   }

.beian {
   font-size:11px;
   text-align: center;
   }
```

I want to fixed the footer vertically at the bottom **while not affecting the page content**

```
the initial code is 

.footer {
   bottom : 2px;  
   height : 40px;  
   margin-top : 40px;  
   text-align: center;  
   vertical-align: middle; 
   position:fixed;
   width:100%;
  left:10%
 }
```

But this setting does not work good in

1: when the viewport is small ( it will mess with the page content)

2: in iphone's landscape mode ( it will again overlap with the content)

So my solution is :

1:when the viewport is smaller than 1000px, apply setting A

2:when the viewport is larger than 1000px & mobile portrait mode, apply setting B

My issue:

1: when the viewport is larger than 1000px the footer is not centered

2: the footer is not fixed to the bottom in mobile portrait mode.

The fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/h6tkgbb8/

Comment: You should make your question simple and clear. 1. What is your problem, 2. Show your whole code (on JSFiddle or Code Snippet), 3. What you want

Comment: Couldn't find the whole code in jsfiddle. Please update it.

Comment: Please update correct part in jsfiddle so that we can check and help you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay and my confusing question. I was not able to get my head straight. What I needed ultimately was to get the footer sticky. I found this link and it solved my problems.

https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">

          content

    <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer"></footer>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;

   /* Equal to height of footer */
   /* But also accounting for potential margin-bottom of last child */
   margin-bottom: -50px;
}
.footer,
.push {
    height: 50px;
 }
```